# create list of dynamically created classes in c#

Tags: c#, wpf, list, class, dynamic

I have created dynamic class using database with name **mMember** and that contains some proeprties . I want to use this property for assigning data to datagrid in wpf.

```
      private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        ICodeCompiler loCompiler = new CSharpCodeProvider().CreateCompiler();
        CompilerParameters loParameters = new CompilerParameters();
        // Start by adding any referenced assemblies
        loParameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.dll");
        // Must create a fully functional assembly as a string
        lcCode = @"public class mMember
        {
            public  static int cid { get; set; }

            public static  string cFname { get; set; }

            public  static string cLname { get; set; }

            public  static decimal? iAge { get; set; }

            public  static string dpDept_Id { get; set; }

            public static  bool? bEnabled { get; set; }
        }";

        // Load the resulting assembly into memory
        loParameters.GenerateInMemory = false;
        // Now compile the whole thing
        CompilerResults loCompiled =
          loCompiler.CompileAssemblyFromSource(loParameters, lcCode);
        if (loCompiled.Errors.HasErrors)
        {
            string lcErrorMsg = "";
            lcErrorMsg = loCompiled.Errors.Count.ToString() +
                         " Errors:";
            for (int x = 0; x < loCompiled.Errors.Count; x++)
                lcErrorMsg = lcErrorMsg + "\r\nLine: " +
                             loCompiled.Errors[x].Line.ToString() +
                              " - " + loCompiled.Errors[x].ErrorText;
            MessageBox.Show(lcErrorMsg + "\r\n\r\n" + lcCode,
                            "Compiler Demo");
            return;
        }
        Assembly loAssembly = loCompiled.CompiledAssembly;
        Type calcType = loAssembly.GetType("mMember");

        // Retrieve an obj ref - generic type only
        object loObject =
               loAssembly.CreateInstance("mMember");
        PropertyInfo numberPropertyInfo = calcType.GetProperty("cLname");

        numberPropertyInfo.SetValue(loObject, "Kadam", null);

        string value = (string)numberPropertyInfo.GetValue(loObject, null);

        var loResult1 = loObject.GetType().GetProperty("cLname").GetValue(this, null);
        MessageBox.Show(loResult1.ToString());

          if (loObject == null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Couldn't load class.");
            return;
        }
   }
```

Now i Want to create list of given properties mentioned in above **dynamically created class** **mMember** and bind this list to **datagrid** in **wpf** .
I want to create List in Given format like **Order** is my class Name and it also contains properties like **mMember** class, but class in in Ready Format. Finally i m binding **orders** to datagrid .

```
      List<Order> orders = new List<Order>();

        for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            orders.Add(new Order() { MB_ID =Convert .ToInt64 ( dt.Rows[i]["MB_ID"]), Name = dt.Rows[i]["MEMBER_NAME"].ToString(), ItemCount = dt.Rows[i]["MB_ID"].ToString(), CompanyId = dt.Rows[i]["COMPANY_ID"].ToString() });
        }
  // Set the data context
        this.DataContext = orders;
```

now I want create similar list for **mMember** class. so I have created instance for same but it didnt work

```
    IList list1 = (IList)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(new Type[] { loObject.GetType() }));
```

how to add **list** data into this and bind to datagrid

Comment: Why... why are you trying to do that in the first place? Whatever you're trying to do, I'm pretty sure there's a simpler way.

Comment: can you please explain it. But for dynamically created class and their Properties. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you need to create a dynamic class?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and was able to solve it with the help of your code combined with the one [here](http://mironabramson.com/blog/post/2008/06/Create-you-own-new-Type-and-use-it-on-run-time-(C).aspx). Your creation code for the list object itself is correct and works. After that you need to fill the list with dynamically created objects. You just Need to create objects e.g. via "object = Activator.CreateInstance(type)", fill them and the add them with "list1.Add(object)".